# How do I delete Albums from Photos for synced folders that don't exist anymore?

Tags: ipod-touch, data-synchronization, photos

I previously used a Windows 7 desktop PC before and synced a folder of pictures to my iPod Touch 4G Photos using iTunes. Unfortunately, the desktop PC crashed and so I had to reinstall Windows 7 on my laptop.

In my current Windows 7 setup on my laptop, I have reorganized my folder structure which included the pictures folders.

So now, I want to sync to these picture folders with my iPod Touch. But first I want to delete a previously synced folder from my iPod Touch (as these will most likely duplicate pictures which are now on different folders). The problem is, I can't do that on the iPod. And I can't do that on iTunes as well because the synced to folder isn't there anymore.

The only thought that occurred to me is to reset the device but I don't want to do this just yet. How do I go about deleting the folder from my photos without touching the other data (e.g. Emails, Messages, etc) on my iPod Touch?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the folders that you want synced, and syncing the devices? I didn't try it just now, but with music, when synced, it deletes anything that is additionally there and not on your current setup. I'm guessing it's the same with photos.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I did and I was able to flush out the existing pictures in iPod synced to the old folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did to erase photos in my iPod Touch synced to a non-existent folder.

1. Created an `empty` folder in my Pictures directory (eg. Temp)
2. Plugged in my iPod Touch, opened iTunes and went to the `Photos` tab and synced to the empty folder
3. Opened the `Photos` app in iPod Touch and album I wanted to remove was removed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You need to sync pictures over it: it will ask you if you want to overwrite the previously synced pictures and you have to click “yes”.

If you just want to get rid of the pictures then select “sync selected folders” without selecting any folders and press the sync button.